# Really bad thoughts I feel like Allahs going to punish me for them

Tags: punishment, evil-thoughts

I’ve been experiencing really bad thoughts since like I went to my home country Bangladesh 5 months ago. A few days later I’ve been starting to pray and being religious for the first time and then I’m getting these bad thoughts that are really bad and I feel like I’m going to be punished.

Will I be punished?
How can I get rid of these thoughts?
I’ve been trying to ignore them but they are too bad and I always ask for forgiveness but I still don’t know what to do.

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To make yourself familiar with our site and our model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. As to your post: Note that we are no peer support nor a usual internet forum. In Islam you may be punished for what you committed, but not for your thoughts as long as they are not been practiced (and then evaluated as sinful). As you didn't reveal what these thoughts are we can't directly address them. As a hint: Knowledge often is a good and strong protection against bad thoughts and doubts seek more knowledge and do good things.

Answer (score 0):

It's a waswas(shaytan whispers) I've been there and i have never got those thoughts before i became religious. it's shaytan trying to trick your mind and trying to lead you astray, just ignore it and recite
أَعُوْذُ بِاللَّهِ مِنَ الشَّيْطَانِ الرَّجِيمِ
"I seek refuge with Allah from the  accursed shaytan" and recite Al-Ikhlas Al-Falaq and An-Nas
Allah Subhannawattaalla wont held you accountable if you dont act upon it and it doesnt take roots in your heart and you utter it, Wallahu A'lam.

Answer (score 0):

Do not worry, if you be quiet, then everything will be ok. This is from the devil. You only need to do is, recite this: I seek refuge from God against the devil. And the devil will go away, because you have somebody being the most powerful( God), and he’s( devil) gonna be afraid to stay with you. Do this for several times, and trust in God.